# Change the jQuery autocomplete box position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been searching for a working solution for almost half a day and even if some of them may seem to work at the first look when the window size is smaller or bigger, it looks messed up. I'll show you what I mean so this question won't be just another duplicate.

Currently, what I have is when the user enters a key into the input box, the yellow table appears and shows the value of the text input.

Nothing is entered:
[image]

The user enters a character into the input box:
[image]

The problem here is that the autocomplete box `.ui-autocomplete` is displayed just below the input box `#search`. It should be displayed below the `table` element so the autocomplete box doesn't hide the `table`. Here is the image how it should look like:
[image]

See the `top` property in the dev tools CSS editor? I've changed it manually and changing this property gives nothing. I've tried many answers in the StackOverflow and nothing worked. That's the answer using the `top` property changer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728786/8889739.

When the user resizes the window, this method doesn't work. I've tried using `px` and `%`. Maybe using `vw` could change something but I'm not sure about it.

```js
var tags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

$("#search").autocomplete({

  source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 5));
  }
});



// ONLY FOR THE #INSTANT-SEARCH FUNCIONALITY >> IGNORE THIS PART
var changeText2 = function(e) {
  var request = $("input").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  $("#instant-search").text(request);

  if (
    $("#instant-search")
    .text()
    .trim().length
  ) {
    $("table").css("display", "table");
  } else {
    $("table").hide();
  }
};

var changeText1 = function(e) {
  $("tr:nth-child(1)").css({
    background: "#ffc800",
    color: "#fff"
  });
  if (
    /[-a-z0-90áãâäàéêëèíîïìóõôöòúûüùçñ!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\s\/]+/gi.test(
      String.fromCharCode(e.which)
    )
  ) {
    $("input").on("keypress", changeText2);
  }

  var getInputSelection = function(input) {
    var start = 0,
      end = 0;
    input.focus();
    if (
      typeof input.selectionStart == "number" &&
      typeof input.selectionEnd == "number"
    ) {
      start = input.selectionStart;
      end = input.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
      var range = document.selection.createRange();
      if (range) {
        var inputRange = input.createTextRange();
        var workingRange = inputRange.duplicate();
        var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
        inputRange.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
        workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", inputRange);
        end = workingRange.text.length;
        workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", inputRange);
        start = workingRange.text.length;
      }
    }
    return {
      start: start,
      end: end,
      length: end - start
    };
  };

  switch (e.key) {
    case "Backspace":
    case "Delete":
      e = e || window.event;
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      var deleteKey = keyCode == 46;
      var sel, deletedText, val;
      val = this.value;
      sel = getInputSelection(this);
      if (sel.length) {
        // 0 kai paprastai trini po viena o 1 ar daugiau kai select su pele trini
        $("#instant-search").text(
          val.substr(0, sel.start) + val.substr(sel.end)
        );
      } else {
        $("#instant-search").text(
          val.substr(0, deleteKey ? sel.start : sel.start - 1) +
          val.substr(deleteKey ? sel.end + 1 : sel.end)
        );
      }
      break;
  }

  if (!$("#instant-search")
    .text()
    .trim().length
  ) {
    $("table").hide();
  }

  $("input").on("input", function(e) {
    $("#instant-search").text($("#search").val());

    if (
      $("#instant-search")
      .text()
      .trim().length
    ) {
      $("table").css("display", "table;");
    } else {
      $("table").hide();
    }
  });
};

$("input").on("keydown", changeText1);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #000428;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #004e92, #000428);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #004e92, #000428);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.v-container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.v-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input input#search {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 15px;
  outline: none;
}

.input button.icon {
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: -50px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s;
  transition: background .5s;
}

.input button.icon:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

table td,
.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:hover,
.ui-menu-item:hover,
.ui-state-active {
  background: #ff3c41;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="v-container">
  <div class="v-content text-center">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
      <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="fa fa-search">
            <td id="instant-search" class="three-dots"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Threads about autocomplete position I've read (and these answers didn't help):

- [Change jQuery UI Autocomplete Position - Pop up, instead of down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728607/change-jquery-ui-autocomplete-position-pop-up-instead-of-down/4728786#4728786)
- [How to position the jQuery autocomplete widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280652/how-to-position-the-jquery-autocomplete-widget)
- [JQuery UI AutoComplete Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603998/jquery-ui-autocomplete-position)
- [jQuery autocomplete : move list position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870625/jquery-autocomplete-move-list-position)

---

**EDIT 1**
I just tried to remove a large part of CSS and one of the methods actually worked. I'm not sure what line was that, maybe I can't remove it but I just wanted to notify you.

Comment: Why don't you just place the table above the input, in the HTML markup?

Comment: Or try using `!important` to force your position.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I could, but I'd like to be able to move it everywhere on the page.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I've already tried it, check the answers which I've seen. Didn't work if the user resizes the page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured the answer by myself. The main problem is I've had a container called `v-container` and its height was set to `100%` so the element didn't even be in the view of the user. With a few changes, everything works fine :)

I've added this line:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  top: auto !important;
}
```

And...

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  appendTo: '.input'
});
```

So the element is in the `.input` container, which is inside the `v-container`, so everything is clean now.